# How to make start/stop time of an AWD RDS MSSQL instance quicker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I start/stop a simple AWS MSSQL RDS instance, it takes 5 minutes, even tho its nearly empty. How come ? Is there a way to make it faster ? Our on-premise MSSQL cluster apparently takes 10 seconds to start

Thanks

Comment: You're able to get a cluster of Windows servers from powered-off to running MSSQL in ten seconds? Database clusters aren't intended to be stopped/started on a whim.

Comment: The 10 seconds was stated in the meeting. And I agree with you, but at job I have a task to evaluate the feasibility of it.

Comment: Sure, but you're evaluating it against incorrect information. You can't start an on-prem MSSQL cluster in 10 seconds, either. I would push back on that piece of information.

Comment: RDS is fairly slow to stop, start, etc, but that's not usually a problem because database servers are rarely restarted. I don't know if you can speed it up, but if you could it would probably be by having a larger instance or faster disk. I've used various sized of Oracle RDS databases, dozens of cores and heaps of RAM, they're still slow to restart.